# Can I use WPF without disabling FIPS compliance?

Tags: c#, wpf, fips

I've seen lots of complaints about build issues (specifically with WPF) with the error:

This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.

Unfortunately, I cannot work-around or disable FIPS compliance on my machine. How can I use WPF without disabling FIPS compliance?

Comment: Try adding <enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/> to both the devenv config and msbuild config

Comment: This is the work-around I've found, but gov't auditors prevent us from using this.

Comment: Are you restricted to a particular version of WPF?

Comment: I don't believe so, is there a version which is FIPS compliant?

Comment: Doesn't look like there is :(

Comment: That's too bad, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured this out. Right before `</runtime>`, Add the line:

```
<enforceFIPSPolicy enabled=“false” />
```

in file `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/msbuild.exe.config`

Adding this to other places will not assist, as this is where WPF project’s MSBuild configurations now live. It has moved around on each version of Microsoft Visual Studio